# For Android Events why are switch statements more common than if-else chains?

Tags: java, android, performance, if-statement, switch-statement

When developing for Android is a switch statement more efficient than an if-else chain? A switch statement takes more lines of code, but looking at anecdotal evidence seems to be the more commonly used in Android applications.

The examples below illustrate the same programming construct with a case statement and if-else chain. The switch statement requires 10 lines while the if-else chain requires 7.

**Case Statement**

```
public void onClickWithSwitch(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()) {
       case R.id.buttonA:
           buttonA();
           break;
       case R.id.buttonB:
           buttonB();
           break;
       case R.id.buttonC:
           buttonC();
   }
}
```

**If-else chain**

```
public void onClickWithIf(View v) {
   int id = v.getId();
   if(id == R.id.buttonA)
       buttonA();
   else if (id == R.id.buttonB)
       buttonB();
   else if (id == R.id.buttonC)
       buttonC();
}
```

Why would switch be more common than an if-else chain? Do switch statements offer better performance when compared to if-else chains?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. And both are the wrong solution in many cases.

Comment: Just edited the title. But I am still don't know for sure if that is what you were talking about. @delnan

Comment: Generally switch is more efficient than if.  Also it can be clearer to show all the comparisons are against the same `id`.  The number of lines of code is a poor indication of efficiency. (you can put your whole program onto one line ut it won't help ;) )

Comment: @George: The use of `switch` over `if` or vice versa isn't what makes a program performant or not. And this kind of `switch` (or `if...else if...`) is usually best replaced by polymorphism.

Comment: @Peter: I already know that lines of code has nothing to do with efficiency.

Comment: What is polymorphism? How would it apply to this situation? @delnan

Comment: If the term "polymorphism" rings no bells, and `virtual` doesn't either, you are either a beginner (in which case, study on - and don't worry about performance for a long time) or you have no business programming an OO language ;) `onClick` should look like `v.doStuff()` and leave the details of what `doStuff` does to the object being clicked.

Comment: @delnan I don't find that to be a beginner question.  You are suggesting applying polymorphism to avoid implementing a switch statement.  This would entail creating a subclass for every single clickable element in a ui.  That seems far more inefficient then writing a switch or if statement in both code complexity and runtime.  Perhaps you didn't notice this is a UI framework?

Comment: @Nick: "What is polymorphism" *is* a beginner question. And yes, polymorphism is only one possible solution. Even though it is the solution that works fine for the GUIs I write (and no, that's not a single class for every clickable element - it's one for every *type* of clickable element). For code size and runtime: Code size increase is negible (well, I don't know how much boilerplace Java requires ;) ), performance hits should be even less noticeable.

Comment: It is considered bad style most of the time to use an if/else statement without {}'s   If you add those in, your line length difference goes away.  In general, switch statements are considered cleaner because it is more clear to the reader what is going on.  However, long if/elses or switch statements should be avoided.  This is probably the one place you need to use it.

Comment: @delnan there are significant performance considerations.  Since the Android SDK defines the only parameter to the onClick callback as a View, you'd have no choice but to delineate between the different classes using introspection and a significant if/else statement of instanceof methods.  On top of this, if you don't have multiple classes (multiple types/objects) then there is no reason to have switch either.  If he was writing the entire framework, making a polymorphic onClick would be an approach to be considered, but given the constraints of the SDK, it makes very little sense.

Comment: @Nick: The Android SDK is *that* constrianted? WTF, but point taken.

Comment: @delnan: I am a Sun Certified Programmer for JDK 1.4 and have been extensively programming in Java and some non OO languages for 4 years since. I am not a beginner (your third comment). It is true that I did not use conventional classes to learn Java - but that has almost nothing to do with familiarity of the language or the real world. Also the word `virtual` does not ring a bell either. I am not **"worried"** about performance. My so called "half baked" performance questions are mostly for curiosity and an attempt to learn more fringe information just by bringing starting up more discussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason languages have `switch` statements is to allow the compiler to generate a jump table, which is fast if it's large, because at run-time it can get to the desired code in O(1) rather than O(N) time.

It's only helpful speed-wise if there are many cases and the code to execute in each case does not take much time, and the program spends much percentage of time in this code at all.

Other than that it's purely a matter of taste.

There is no relationship between number of code lines and speed. What matters is the kind of assembly language code that's generated, which I'd encourage you to get familiar with.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your sequence of ifs/cases is truly vast, I don't think it matters. With the switch statement, it's more clear what's going on. The only downside is all the `break` statements and the potential to miss one, but a static analyzer should catch that.

Best would be a map keyed by the id or some clever use of subclassing

Comment: NetBeans does catch missing breaks and put in a warning for me.

Comment: missing breaks are the result of horrible programming practices (much like what is seen in the original post).  If you don't automatically include a break immediately after your case, then you get what's coming to you.

Comment: Are you saying that I should have put a break at the end of the last case? @Kevin

Comment: @George Bailey: adding a break at the end of the last case is a good idea, just in case someone adds a new case at the end and doesn't notice that it's missing.

Comment: Absolutely yes.  One of the benefits of the switch is that it provides the capability to 'fall through'.  It is also one of the greatest drawbacks.  Any 'missing' break statement should be documented in the code; this will stop the next developer from 'fixing' your code by inserting the missing break(s).

Comment: @George - YES as otherwise WHEN (not if) you/another dev come's back to the code, go to add another case, your just asking for errors.

Answer (score 3):

"More efficient" is a vague concept, because there are so many ways to measure it. I suppose most people think of execution time. On the other hand, most people don't think of memory efficiency. A switch statement with widely spaced test values can be a horrible memory hog, unless the compiler is smart enough to re-interpret it as an if-else chain.

There's a lot to be said, as well, for programming efficiency, including maintenance and readability. As sblundy noted, a switch statement can be clearer about the programmer's intent than an if-else chain. Comments can counterbalance that, but that requires more work for the programmer and there's also the risk that the comments and code don't match (particularly after a few maintenance cycles).

I imagine that most people follow whatever style they have been taught (or told to follow), without thinking about it too much. The rest of the time, I think most decisions about switch vs. if-else are based on which one best matches the programmer's thinking at the moment the code is being generated.

Answer (score 2):

You asked: Is a switch statement really more efficient?

Anybody claiming to have a definitive and general answer on this question, talks nonsense. There is exactly one way to find out which is faster in your case: Use a proper micro-benchmarking framework on your target plattform with your complete software, not a simplified example. If that reveals a measurable and statistically signifanct difference I'd be interested in hearing about it. I doubt you'll find any measurable difference for a real program.

Therefore, I would strictly go for readability.

Answer (score 2):

While we're on the subject, nobody mentioned that you should ***always*** have a `default` line in switch statement. Usually you want to throw an exception, but at least you should assert and/or log the error.

This is just good basic defensive programming. It alerts you that you have a programming error if you later add another button (in this case).

Comment: Actually, a `default` case is often a bad idea when switching on an `enum`. It prevents the ide from warning when you have missed a case (assuming that you have turned on this warning, which is a good idea). Much better in those situations to explicitly list all the enum cases (if any) for which you want to do the default stuff.